# UPDATE Query error MariaDB

Tags: php, html, mysqli

> Error code: 
> ERROR: Could not able to execute UPDATE se_players SET (teamname, playername, positie, steamid, land, facebook WHERE playername='Nox') VALUES ('Nox', 'Hugo', 'Player', '1415121512', 'CA', 'testfbpage'). You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(teamname, playername, positie, steamid, land, facebook WHERE playername='Nox') ' at line 1    ?>

**Bewerken-form.php**

```
<form action="../functions/bewerken-update.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="oudespelersnaam">Oude spelersnaam:</label>
        <input type="text" name="teamname" id="teamname" placeholder="Oude spelersnaam">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="playername">Nieuw spelernaam:</label>
        <input type="text" name="playername" id="playername" placeholder="Nieuwe spelersnaam">
    </p>    
    <p>
        <label for="positie">Nieuwe Positie:</label>
        <input type="text" name="positie" id="positie" placeholder="Nieuwe positie">
    </p>    
    <p>
        <label for="steamid">Nieuwe SteamID:</label>
        <input type="text" name="steamid" id="steamid" placeholder="Wat na /id/ komt *12452346346*">
    </p>    
    <p>
        <label for="land">Nieuw Land:</label>
        <input type="text" name="land" id="land" placeholder="NL / BE / US / CA / UK">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="facebook">Nieuw Facebook:</label>
        <input type="text" name="facebook" id="facebook" placeholder="facebook.com/naam">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Speler aanpassen">
</form>
```

**Bewerken-update.php**

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("********", "********", "********", "********");

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$teamname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['teamname']);

$playername = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['playername']);

$positie = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['positie']);

$steamid = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['steamid']);

$land = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['land']);

$facebook = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['facebook']);    

$sql = "UPDATE se_players SET (teamname, playername, positie, steamid, land, facebook WHERE playername='$teamname') VALUES ('$teamname', '$playername', '$positie', '$steamid', '$land', '$facebook')";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Spelers bijgewerkt.";
} 
else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Sorry if it's a simple fix but i'm lost.

Comment: you're using the wrong mysql function

Comment: `UPDATE` syntax is `SET column=value, column=value, ...`. You are using `INSERT` syntax -> `(column, column,...) VALUES (value, value, ...)` on your `UPDATE`.

Comment: this is a typo question

Comment: Your query syntax is somewhere between an update and an insert.  Build yourself a test query and get it working, _then_ add it to your php.  Something like `UPDATE table SET column=value, column@=value WHERE... `. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/update/

Comment: Thanks @Sean modified it to:     $sql = "UPDATE se_players SET playername='$playername', positie='$positie', steamid='$steamid', land='$land', facebook='$facebook' WHERE playername='$teamname'"; and now its working fine.

Comment: I removed  (solved) from the title. Either delete the question or post your own answer. This is still a typo question, IMHO.